# react js mongodb query issue

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i'm having an issue querying my mongodb database. i'm using react js. the problem doesn't seem to be the connection because i can save to the database just fine, i can only assume its a syntax issue. i've looked around but couldn't find a fix. below is a snippet of code from the schema.js file and the index.js file:

Schema.js

```js
//import dependency
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
//create new instance of the mongoose.schema. the schema takes an
//object that shows the shape of your database entries.
var UserSchema = new Schema({
 socketId: String
})
//export our module to use in server.js
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

index.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongodatabase', {
  useMongoClient: true,
  /* other options */
})
var UserSchema = require('../schema/Schemas');
```

```js
function userExist(userList, username){
    var usert = new UserSchema()
    var query = usert.where({socketId: username})
    query.findOne(function (err, usert) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      if (usert) {
        // doc may be null if no document matched
      }
    });
   return username in userList
    // return query
}
```

I get the error : usert.where is not a function. 
i tried using just find but i get the same error

any help would be welcome, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [.findOne function](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOne) directly on your schema class instead of `.where`

Like this :

```
UserSchema.findOne({socketId: username}, function (err, usert) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  if (usert) {
    // doc may be null if no document matched
  }
});
```

.where must be used on query, not schema.

To use [.where](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.where), you can do it like this :

```
User.findOne().where({ socketId: username }).exec( function (err, usert) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  if (usert) {
    // doc may be null if no document matched
  }
})
```

Comment: just tried that i get the error: TypeError: usert.findOne is not a function

Comment: Yep, I just updated the answer, I didn't see that you used new Schema()

Comment: Awesome it works. at least it doesn't crash. why is that so though?

Comment: 2 mistakes in your original code. `new UserChema()` create a new instance of User and does not allow you to perform a request. And .where need to be called on a query. I will add an example with .where syntax in the answer

Comment: here is the `.where` example. Do not hesitate to mark as solved if the answer solves your problem.

Comment: awesome Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more question if i may, it seems that this returns after my function returns is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: No this, is the way nodejs works. It becomes asynchronous at each I/O. To avoid it, you must retun a Promise in your function (you can use await / async syntax if you are with node => 8)